# Thinking of switching from Win10 to Ubuntu. Installing Ubuntu on NVME

Tags: system-installation, uefi, bios, nvme

Thinking of switching from Win10 to Ubuntu. I plan to get a new laptop with a 250gb or 500gb NVME SSD C drive just for the OS and a 2tb spinning drive (D drive) for all data and files. I plan to select a laptop from this list: https://certification.ubuntu.com/desktop

- My assumption is that it is straightforward to install Ubuntu on an NVME drive. True?
- My assumption is that Ubuntu no longer has problems being installed on laptops with UEFI. This true?

Thanks. Just want to make the switch to Ubuntu with eyes wide open. I'm a beginner with computer tech.
.
.

Comment: If you plan on picking up a certified device new, perhaps you should consider getting one with Ubuntu pre-installed. This way you don't have to worry about whether the hardware is properly supported or not. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My assumption is that it is straightforward to install Ubuntu on an NVME drive. True?

Yes

> My assumption is that Ubuntu no longer has problems being installed on laptops with UEFI. This true?

Yes

Answer (score 1):

I do not have any experience with NVME drives, but my laptop also has a UEFI. I am now using a dual-boot and Ubuntu doesn't have issues with my bios.

For safety, for if it goes wrong, make a windows usb installation media before you install Ubuntu.

O jea, and your C/D drive letters will be removed while installing Ubuntu. So you can only use disk size and model number to identify your ssd.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but there may be a few problems. The installer may not recognize the SSD. Here's a solution:
From another solution, and iTecTec

> The issue was related to BIOS settings, SATA MODE was set to Raid while it should be AHCI, also I had to close the secure boot to enable the installation.

Other than that, you should be all good.